# HackerRank SQL Challenges: Subqueries

Tags: mysql

The HackerRank Question is [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/challenges/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen).

My code for this challenge is in MySQL:

```
SELECT c.hacker_id as id, h.name as name, COUNT(c.hacker_id) as cnt
FROM hackers h INNER JOIN challenges c
ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY c.hacker_id
HAVING cnt in (
    SELECT MAX(Counter1)
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as Counter1
        FROM challenges c1
        GROUP BY c1.hacker_id
        ORDER BY Counter1, c1.hacker_id
    ) LIMIT 1
) OR IN (
    SELECT Counter2
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as Counter2
        FROM challenges c2
        GROUP BY c2.hacker_id
        HAVING Counter2=1
    )
)
ORDER BY cnt DESC, id;
```

But the error says

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (
> SELECT Counter2
> FROM (
> SELECT COUNT(*) as Counter2
> ' at line 13

How shall I correct my answer? How do I improve my running speed? and I am confused about the rules that when shall I give alias to subqueries table and when shall not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a with clause and define your counts there and pass it in the having clause.

Answer (score 0):

It sux.. they have a pretty low version of mysql -> see the output for "select version()"

`5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`

Anyway.. if you wanna stick with MySQL you would have to repeat your "core" query multiple times :( this version does not support WITH clause .. which makes it more readable ...

```sql
/*
Enter your query here.
*/
SELECT a.hacker_id
, a.name
, a.ch_cnt as challenges_created
FROM ( -- get all challenges
    SELECT h.hacker_id
    , h.name
    , count(c.challenge_id) as ch_cnt
    FROM hackers h
    LEFT JOIN challenges c
    ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
    WHERE 1=1
    GROUP BY h.hacker_id
    , h.name
  ) a
--
LEFT JOIN ( -- tag challenges with duplicate numbers (>1)
    SELECT ch_cnt
    , count(*) as dupl
    FROM (
        SELECT h.hacker_id
        , h.name
        , count(c.challenge_id) as ch_cnt
        FROM hackers h
        LEFT JOIN challenges c
        ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
        WHERE 1=1
        GROUP BY h.hacker_id
        , h.name
       ) bb
    GROUP BY ch_cnt
    HAVING count(*) > 1
  ) b
ON a.ch_cnt = b.ch_cnt
--
LEFT JOIN ( -- tag challenges with the max count
    SELECT max(ch_cnt) ch_cnt
    FROM (
        SELECT h.hacker_id
        , h.name
        , count(c.challenge_id) as ch_cnt
        FROM hackers h
        LEFT JOIN challenges c
        ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
        WHERE 1=1
        GROUP BY h.hacker_id
        , h.name
       ) cc
  ) c
ON a.ch_cnt = c.ch_cnt
--
WHERE 1=1
AND (
      b.ch_cnt IS NULL -- remove duplicates
      OR c.ch_cnt IS NOT NULL -- keep the duplicates for the max nbr of challenges
    ) 
--
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 1 ASC
```

winning query: Congratulations!